# Java: Wrong hour from Calendar instance?

Tags: java, calendar

Running :

```
public class test {
    @Test
    public void displayDate() {
        SimpleDateFormat MONTH_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM", Locale.getDefault());
        String testDateStr = "2017-07-01T07:58:23.000Z";
        Calendar calendar = getFormatedDate(testDateStr);
        int yearInt  = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        String monthStr = MONTH_FORMAT.format(calendar.getTime()).toUpperCase();
        int monthInt = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dayInt  = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int hour24 = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int min = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int sec = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        System.out.println(testDateStr);
        System.out.println(String.format("%s-%s-%s %s:%s:%s", yearInt, monthStr, dayInt, hour24, min, sec));
        System.out.println(String.format("%s-%s-%s %s:%s:%s", yearInt, monthInt, dayInt, hour24, min, sec));

    }

    private Calendar getFormatedDate(String dateStr) {
        Instant instant;
        try {
            instant = Instant.parse(dateStr);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());
        Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.from(zdt);
        return calendar;
    }
}
```

I'm getting:

```
2017-07-01T07:58:23.000Z
2017-JUL-1 9:58:23
2017-6-1 9:58:23
```

Notice I'm getting hour = 9 while expected 7

**Questions**

1. Why this result
2. How to get the right result ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why do you think this is the wrong result?  Presumably your default time zone is either 10 hours ahead of UTC, or two hours behind, right?

Comment: The ZoneOffset is `000Z` so expecting no offset

Comment: Since you can use the modern date-time classes (`Instant`, `ZonedDateTIme` and `ZoneId`, all from java.time), I recommend you use java.time exclusively and evict the poorly designed and now outdated `SimpleDateFormat`,, `Calendar` and `GregorianCalendar` from your code. It will make you code both simpler and clearer. java.time has all the functionality you need and more.

Comment: Just to set things straight: `.000` is the fraction of second (0 milliseconds if you like). `Z` is the zone offset (no offset, correct).

Comment: Is printing a `monthInt` of **6** for **July** desired? July is the 7th month, so it seems confusing to me.

Comment: If you absolutely need a `Calendar` and your real purpose was to unit test the `Calendar` you get: I don’t think there’s any need to test its individual fields (year, month, day, hour of day, etc.). I’d accept testing its `toInstant` and `getTimeZone`, then it follows that the fields are correct too.

Comment: Yes, but you've parsed the instant in UTC, then pulled the individual fields out using your own time zone.  Since your time zone is not UTC, you've introduced a difference by doing that.  The answer seems correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why this result

Due to this line:
`ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());`
You're forcing **your time zone** over the one defined in the `dateStr`, so the Calendar will use your time zone instead of the original one.

> How to get the right result ?

Change your `getFormatedDate` method to:

```
private Calendar getFormatedDate(final String dateStr) {
    final ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateStr);
    return GregorianCalendar.from(zdt);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. It work. Marked answered and up voted!

Comment: If the asker really (as in really, really) needs a `Calendar` object (typically for a legacy API that they cannot afford to upgrade), this answer is correct. Normally one wouldn’t use `ZonedDateTime` for parsing a string with `Z` offset, but since we need one for producing the `Calendar`, it seems the correct way to go in this particular case.